# ASP.Net Active Directories get groups works on local box but not on web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I have code that will return the groups from AD for any specific user.  Works great locally on my development box. When I try to run it on the web server it will not complete the code but throws an error then returns.  I though this may have something to do with permissions so I added a piece to impersonate an admin account when the code is finished getting the groups it undoes the impersonation.  That code does not throw an error, however it also does not return a list of groups.

```
public static List<GroupPrincipal> GetUserGroups(string userName)
{

    bool isImper = impersonateValidUser("user", "domain", "password");
    List<GroupPrincipal> result = new List<GroupPrincipal>();

    // establish domain context
    PrincipalContext yourDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,"WYSD");

    // find your user
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(yourDomain, userName);

    // if found - grab its groups
    if (user != null)
    {
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

        // iterate over all groups
        foreach (Principal p in groups)
        {
            // make sure to add only group principals
            if (p is GroupPrincipal)
            {
                result.Add((GroupPrincipal)p);
            }
        }
    }
    undoImpersonation();
    try
    {
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.WriteLog("Error in retriving form data: " + ex.Message);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return GetUserGroups(userName);
    }
}
```

The `Thread.Sleep` in the catch is used for a workaround for an issue in .NET 4.0 at the moment.
If I use the code locally with impersonation, or without, it works fine. The code for impersonation is below:

```
public static bool impersonateValidUser(String userName, String domain, String password)
{
    System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
    IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
    IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;
    if(userName.Contains("\\")){
        userName = userName.Substring(userName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
    }
    if (LogonUser(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
    {
        if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
        {
            tempWindowsIdentity = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
            impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
            if (impersonationContext != null)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
public static void undoImpersonation()
{
    impersonationContext.Undo();
}


#region | Property |
// property getters/setters
public string DomainName { get; set; }
public string LoginPath { get; set; }
public string LoginUsername { get; set; }
public string LoginPassword { get; set; }
public System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes AuthenticationType { get; set; }
public System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry Ad { get { return Ad; } set { Ad = value; } }
#endregion

#region | Impersonation via interop |
//need to import from COM via InteropServices to do the impersonation when saving the details
public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
static System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;

[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int LogonUser(String lpszUserName, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public extern static int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken, int impersonationLevel, ref IntPtr hNewToken);
#endregion
```

Now I guess the question is, first do I need impersonation and if not why does the code not work.  Second if I need impersonation, why do I not get back my groups?

Comment: Have you tried just simply supplying the user credentials on the creation of the PrincipalContext (instead of Impersonation)? Try:  `PrincipalContext yourDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "WYSD", "user", "password");` - does that work now?

Comment: Not to sound completely lost, but does your example use the user and password of the user I am trying to get groups for or is that for a user that has access to the AD?

Comment: You should put in the credentials of the user you've used to **impersonate** - not the one you want to get the groups for, the one you're trying to use to access the Active Directory

Comment: That didn't seem to help either.  Not sure what is going on

Comment: Does it return some kind of a warning/error message at all? Or just doesn't retrieve anything?

Comment: I get a message, "StackTrace":"", ExceptionType":"".  I have tried multiple ways to get a better error message but nothing seems to work, including writing to a log file and using throw new Exception.  If there is a better way to get groups from AD based on a user name I am will to try that.  I am using .Net 4.0.